# Android intent not firing in chrome 53.0.2785.124

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent

We are having an android app which we want to fire when a file is loaded from a url. Below is the intent configuration we are using

We have created a custom mime type for our application

```
   <intent-filter>                 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
           <data
               android:pathPattern=".*\\cloudconfig"
               android:mimeType="application/x-securew2-cloudconfig"/>

       </intent-filter>
```

The above configuration was working fine in all browsers and all versions of chrome except chrome 53.0.2785.124. We suspect that this could be a potential bug with chrome. If there are any workarounds, please suggest.

Any suggestions much appreciated

Comment: what is the value of this url?

Comment: please visit the below link to download our app
http://demo7.securew2.com/public/31/sudhakar-tls1/?device=Android

When the app is downloaded, use the join now button. It downloads a file from the below llink
http://demo7.securew2.com/public/31/sudhakar-tls1/android/SecureW2.cloudconfig

Comment: what is " \\" for in "pathPattern"?

Comment: Thats a standard for how to give escape \

Comment: i know that "\\"` in java string really means "\", the question is what do you need that "\" for?

Comment: we are looking for a particular string in the URL. The String can end with \cloudconfig